# How to delete files in directory

Tags: linux, shell

I have to delete one particular file in each directory.

Example: MKRUW, DKRUW, TKRUW 
In each of these directories I need to enter MKRUW/default/file and delete .dat files.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `MKRUW`, `DKRUW`, etc. are directories.  Go the the parent directory of each of these directories, and try:

`find . -name '*.dat'`

If you're satisfied with the list of found `.dat` files and you wish to proceed with deleting these, run the same search again but with added arguments to remove the files:

`find . -name '*.dat' -exec rm -f {} \;`

Of course, you're free to change `*.dat` into something less general. For example, if you wish to only remove files named `info.dat`, you would use `find . -name 'info.dat'`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `MKRUW`, `DKRUW`, `TKRUW` are directories and that within each of these, you want to delete files matching `default/file/*.dat`, and that you are running a reasonably modern shell, you can use:

```
echo {MKRUW,DKRUW,TKRUW}/default/file/*.dat
```

to get a list of the names of the files in question.

When you are satisfied that this is the list that you want to delete, merely substitute `rm` for `echo`:

```
rm {MKRUW,DKRUW,TKRUW}/default/file/*.dat
```

This works because `{...,...,...}` is expanded by the shell (in much the same way as `*.dat`) by exploding the argument into a larger number of arguments, one for each matching entry. Those arguments are then passed to the command, which in the above cases are `echo` and `rm` respectively. Hence, the above `rm` command is equivalent to, but requires much less typing than:

```
rm MKRUW/default/file/*.dat DKRUW/default/file/*.dat TKRUW/default/file/*.dat
```